# Slow boot after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, 16.04, startup

A few days ago I finally got round to upgrading to 16.04 from a clean install of 15.10. Everything works fine, but boot takes a lot longer than before with no splash screen (just blinking cursor in top left) and an extra motherboard beep after selecting OS. Running `systemd-analyze blame` gives the largest culprits as:

```
34.073s plymouth-quit-wait.service
33.941s apt-daily.service
33.941s gpu-manager.service
33.828s snapd.refresh.service
2.397s upower.service
```

Does anyone know what the problem could be? During the update I was given the option to update `/etc/default/rcS` or leave as is. Having never knowingly changed this, after my brief research into what it was I decided to update it. Could this be related to the issue?